# Remove all external links from posts

Tags: posts, links

I have website what contain hundreads articles.
is there some way, how to remove all external links from all posts by one click/script?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by a SQL query, example:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = CONCAT(
    LEFT(post_content, LOCATE('<a', post_content) - 1), 
    SUBSTRING(post_content, LOCATE('</a>', post_content, LOCATE('<a', post_content) + 2) + 4))
WHERE post_content LIKE '%<a%';
```